# jQuery .load on image fires once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

## Context

A user page with HR information.

I have a menu under the user picture which has an unfixed size.

I update the menu `margin-top` when the picture is loaded:

```
_setMenuMarginTop: function () {
    var that = this;

    $('#picture > img').load(function () {
        that.$el.css('margin-top', $(this).height() + 'px');
    });
}
```

When the current user is changing, I update the page (user info, user picture img) then I recall the method `_setMenuMarginTop` as the picture size isn't the same:

```
initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(app.curUser, 'sync', this._updateView);
},

...

_updateView: function () {
    this._setMenuMarginTop();

    // Other stuffs...
},
```

But this time jQuery doesn't fire the `.load` method.

## Questions

- Any idea why?
- Does it work only once?
- Workaround?

## More info

The img update into an other view:

```
initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(app.curUser, 'sync', this._updateCurUserInfo);
}

...

_updateCurUserInfo: function () {
    this.$el.find('#picture').html( this.templatePicture({ 'url' : getPictureUrl(app.curUser.get('picture')) }) );

    // Other stuffs...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about triggering the onload handler again ?

```
_setMenuMarginTop: function () {
    var that = this;

    $('#picture > img').on('load', function () {
        that.$el.css('margin-top', $(this).height() + 'px');
    }).each(function() {
         if (this.complete) $(this).trigger('load');
    });
}
```

And note that's it's an event handler, calling the function again just applies another event handler.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the new image doesn't have the load function on it. Replacing the image breaks the event. You can use the jQuery `on` function to always fire the event on all images that are in the #picture div:

```
$('#picture').on('load', 'img', function() {
    that.$el.css('margin-top', $(this).height() + 'px');
})
```

That should do it. This would replace your `$('#picture > img').load(function () {` line

What this does is attach the event to the '#picture' div, but actually fire when an 'img' inside the #picture div is loaded.

This way, if the picture is removed, the event isn't removed as well.

Comment: I agree with you about the logic, so I tested it and that doesn't work, the selector `$('#picture').on('load', 'img', ...` is never fired, even the first time. :s

Answer (score 0):

I believe assigned image `src` should be different each time for `load` to fire. Consider following demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/j4tP8/1/**

I am using basic image and button

```
<button id="one">One</button>
<img id="img" />
```

Which connected via

```
$('#one').click(function() {
    $('#img').attr('src','https://site/image.jpg')
})

$('#img').load(function() {
    alert('loaded');
})
```

When you click the button - image is assigned source. As it is `load` event will fire only once. But f you modify the code by adding random string to the source:

```
$('#one').click(function() {
    $('#img').attr('src','https://site/image.jpg?' + Math.random() )
})
```

`load` will fire every time.

Comment: I edited my question, actually it isn't the `src` I update but the whole `<img>`.

Comment: Can you try 'randomizing' that image's src as a test?